# How to send AWS CLI data sync failure notification via email?

Tags: batch-file, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have `.bat` file inside that calls the AWS `sync` command:

```
aws s3 sync D:\Users\backup s3://mybucket
```

It syncs my local data to an S3 bucket. Then I created a Windows Scheduler Task for that `.bat` file, and every day at 2300hr the `.bat` file runs and syncs my local data to the S3 bucket.

If a failure happens during the sync on the local PC (example: network failure/s3 authentication fail) or remote S3 server, I want to get a failure notification via email.

What is the best and most efficient way to get this notification?

Answer (score 2):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) can return an error code to indicate whether the command succeeded.

See: [AWS CLI Return Codes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/return-codes.html)

Therefore, you could do the following:

- When running a CLI command, redirect output to a temporary file
- Check the return code. If it is non-zero, send an email with the error code and the contents of the temporary file

It would be something like:

```
aws s3 cp ./foo s3://bar >output
code=$?
if [ $code -ne 0 ]
then <email stuff with output file>
fi
```